# Question fixed but too late to be reopened in queue

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

I ran across the question [Stop Windows NLA from repeatedly detecting local network as a new, Unidentified Network](https://superuser.com/q/1283316/213131) in the Reopen queue after it had already received several Leave Closed votes. It was suffering from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445), so I gave it some needed attention and edited it to pose a proper question.

Unfortunately, it left the queue before enough users could see the edited post. I feel the question deserves to be reopened, and would have had it had more exposure after being edited.

**Can this question be reopened?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You flag it.

Or you post on meta

Reopened with 3 reopen votes ;p

Comment: I didn't flag it because I felt that would be presumptive on my part to assume there was no discussion needed...after all there was one more close vote cast after my edit while it was still in the queue.